# How to translate the intro ML.Net demo to F#?

Tags: .net, f#, ml.net

I'm looking at a the cs file here:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet/get-started/windows
and in my attempt to translate it to F# it compiles just fine but throws a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` when run: `FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format`. What am I missing?

#### Editted: Was using records before

```
open Microsoft.ML
open Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api
open Microsoft.ML.Trainers
open Microsoft.ML.Transforms
open System

type IrisData = 
    [<Column("0")>] val mutable SepalLength : float
    [<Column("1")>] val mutable SepalWidth : float
    [<Column("2")>] val mutable PetalLength : float
    [<Column("3")>] val mutable PetalWidth : float
    [<Column("4");ColumnName("Label")>] val mutable Label : string

    new(sepLen, sepWid, petLen, petWid, label) = 
        { SepalLength = sepLen
          SepalWidth = sepWid
          PetalLength = petLen
          PetalWidth =  petWid
          Label = label }

type IrisPrediction = 
    [<ColumnName("PredictedLabel")>] val mutable PredictedLabels : string
    new() = { PredictedLabels = "Iris-setosa" }


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let pipeline = new LearningPipeline()
    let dataPath = "iris.data.txt"
    pipeline.Add(new TextLoader<IrisData>(dataPath,separator = ","))
    pipeline.Add(new Dictionarizer("Label"))
    pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator("Features", "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"))
    pipeline.Add(new StochasticDualCoordinateAscentClassifier())
    pipeline.Add(new PredictedLabelColumnOriginalValueConverter(PredictedLabelColumn = "PredictedLabel") )    
    let model = pipeline.Train<IrisData, IrisPrediction>()


    let prediction = model.Predict(IrisData(3.3, 1.6, 0.2, 5.1,""))

    Console.WriteLine("Predicted flower type is: {prediction.PredictedLabels}")

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: F# equivalent to C# `IrisData` and `IrisPrediction` classes used in the tutorial are custom types (POCOs), not F# records used in your code.

Comment: Using POCOs still throws the same error.

Comment: Fields in your POCOs are not `public` as in C#.

Comment: Note that there is no longer a need for ugly mutable fields: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/pull/616 . So the style of code in the question and answers doesn't correspond to the current state of ML.Net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find below a working F# version of code for the [ML tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet/get-started/windows), using Microsoft.ML 0.1.0 (might break with newer versions). Two major differences from your code that make the sample work are both within `IrisData` and `IrisPrediction`type definitions:

- Accurate presentation of C# POCO in F# having parameterless constructor and public access to the fields
- Correct porting of C# `float` to F#, which is `float32`

Here is the code

```
open Microsoft.ML
open Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api
open Microsoft.ML.Trainers
open Microsoft.ML.Transforms
open System

type IrisData() =
    [<Column("0")>]
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable public SepalLength: float32
    [<DefaultValue>]
    [<Column("1")>]
    val mutable public SepalWidth: float32
    [<DefaultValue>]
    [<Column("2")>]
    val mutable public PetalLength:float32
    [<DefaultValue>]
    [<Column("3")>]
    val mutable public PetalWidth:float32
    [<DefaultValue>]
    [<Column("4")>]
    [<ColumnName("Label")>]
    val mutable public Label:string

type IrisPrediction() =
    [<ColumnName("PredictedLabel")>]
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable public PredictedLabel : string

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let pipeline = new LearningPipeline()
    let dataPath = "iris.data.txt"
    let a = IrisPrediction()
    pipeline.Add(new TextLoader<IrisData>(dataPath,separator = ","))
    pipeline.Add(new Dictionarizer("Label"))
    pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator("Features", "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"))
    pipeline.Add(new StochasticDualCoordinateAscentClassifier())
    pipeline.Add(new PredictedLabelColumnOriginalValueConverter(PredictedLabelColumn = "PredictedLabel") )    
    let model = pipeline.Train<IrisData, IrisPrediction>()

    let x = IrisData()
    x.SepalLength <- 3.3f
    x.SepalWidth <- 1.6f
    x.PetalLength <- 0.2f
    x.PetalWidth <- 5.1f
    let prediction = model.Predict(x)

    printfn "Predicted flower type is: %s"  prediction.PredictedLabel

    0
```

and the output it produces:

```
Automatically adding a MinMax normalization transform, use 'norm=Warn' or 'norm=No' to turn this behavior off.
Using 4 threads to train.
Automatically choosing a check frequency of 4.
Auto-tuning parameters: maxIterations = 9996.
Auto-tuning parameters: L2 = 2.668802E-05.
Auto-tuning parameters: L1Threshold (L1/L2) = 0.
Using best model from iteration 892.
Not training a calibrator because it is not needed.
Predicted flower type is: Iris-virginica
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: As of today (Microsoft.ML 0.2), this needs an additional `open Microsoft.ML.Data` in the header and `pipeline.Add(TextLoader(dataPath).CreateFrom<IrisData>(separator=','))` to load the CSV, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910370/am-i-using-textloader-wrong-when-running-the-ml-net-iris-demo-in-f