# Am I using TextLoader wrong when running the ML.Net Iris demo in F#?

Tags: f#, ml.net

I am new to F#/.NET and I am trying to run the F# example provided in the accepted answer of [How to translate the intro ML.Net demo to F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322653/how-to-translate-the-intro-ml-net-demo-to-f) with the [ML.NET library](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet/get-started/windows), using F# on Visual Studio, using Microsoft.ML (0.2.0).

When building it I get the error `error FS0039: The type 'TextLoader' is not defined.`

To avoid this, I added the line

```
open Microsoft.ML.Data
```

to the source. 
Then, however, the line

```
pipeline.Add(new TextLoader<IrisData>(dataPath,separator = ","))
```

triggers:
`error FS0033: The non-generic type 'Microsoft.ML.Data.TextLoader' does not expect any type arguments, but here is given 1 type argument(s)`

Changing to:

```
pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(dataPath,separator = ","))
```

yields:
`error FS0495: The object constructor 'TextLoader' has no argument or settable return property 'separator'. The required signature is TextLoader(filePath: string) : TextLoader.`

Changing to:

```
pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(dataPath))
```

makes the build successful, but the code fails when running with 
`ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Column #1 not found in the dataset (it only has 1 columns)`, I assume because the comma separator is not correctly picked up (incidentally, you can find and inspect the iris dataset at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data).

Also

```
pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(dataPath).CreateFrom<IrisData>(separator: ','))
```

won't work.

I understand that there have been changes in `TextLoader` recently (see e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/332), can somebody point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try updating the NuGet package to make sure it's at 0.2. But yes, the API for that has changed to something like `new TextLoader(_dataPath).CreateFrom<SentimentData>(separator: ',')`

Comment: Oh, sorry, my F# has gotten quite stale. Try this instead: `pipeline.Add(TextLoader(_dataPath).CreateFrom<SentimentData>(separator: ','))`

Comment: Also, there's a [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/pull/7) currently on the samples repo for F#.

Comment: This looks like it doesn't have any compilation errors for me: `pipeline.Add(TextLoader(_dataPath).CreateFrom<SentimentData>(separator=','))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# just has a bit of a different syntax that can take some getting used to. It doesn't use the `new` keyword to instantiate a new class and to use named parameters it uses the `=` instead of `:` that you would in C#.

So for this line in C#:

```
pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(dataPath).CreateFrom<IrisData>(separator: ','))
```

It would be this in F#:

```
pipeline.Add(TextLoader(dataPath).CreateFrom<IrisData>(separator=','))
```