# How do I specify a target architecture when building projects in Visual Studio code?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, f#-fake, ionide, ml.net

I am new to VS code/F# and I am trying to build a F# console app (on both Windows workstation and on my Linux computer).

I installed the Ionide extension together with FAKE.

The code I am considering is the Iris example (see [How to translate the intro ML.Net demo to F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322653/how-to-translate-the-intro-ml-net-demo-to-f)), creating a New F# Project with Ionide and using Microsoft.ML.

My `iris.fsproj` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="iris.fs" />
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />
</Project>
```

When running the script (which I do with the "play" button aka F#: run script provided with VS Code/Ionide) I get:

`C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml\0.2.0\build\Microsoft.ML.targets(16,5): error : Microsoft.ML currently supports 'x64' processor architectures. Please ensure your application is targeting 'x64'.`

together with

`Running build failed.
Error:
System.Exception: dotnet build failed`

How do I target x64 with the project structure provided by Ionide?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be as simple as adding the following line to your `PropertyGroup` section:

```
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

There are more complicated setups possible using the `Condition` attribute to set the platform target based on various command-line arguments to the compiler, but that should be the simplest way to get you up and running.